# is this set already closed?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds, low-dimensional-topology

Let the set

$D=\{(x, y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|0 < x^2 + y^2 \leq 4\}$

is this set closed?

I know that this set is closed if $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash D$ is open.

The set $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash D=\{0\}\cup \{(x, y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x^2 + y^2 > 4\}$

The set $\{(x, y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x^2 + y^2 > 4\}$ is already open, but the one point set $\{0\}$ is closed

I don't know if this union is already open. I guess that it's not open, nor closed; but i'm not so sure about it.

Comment: $(0,0)$ is a limit point, does it belong to the set ?

Comment: (0,0) doesn't belong to D, but it does for its complement

Comment: Alternatively: $(0,0)$ is in the complement, but is there a ball of center $(0,0)$ in the complement too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ iff for any point $x \in S$, there exists an $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $x$ which is contained in $S$.

In our case, i.e. $S = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus D$, any $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $(0,0)$ is not contained in $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus D$.
This implies that $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus D$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and hence $D$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$.